# How can I use the following formula to determine the value of a variable?

Tags: c#, math, mathematical-optimization, discrete-mathematics, polynomial-math

How can I use the following formula to determine the value of a variable?

**Before someone suggests this is off topic**, I am not on Stack-overflow to determine what formula to use. **I am here so I can figure out how to utilise the formula via c#**.

**Background:**

I had previously opened a thread on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com) so someone there could help me generate a forumla which would create the following sequence: 1 , 7 , 14, 30. A user there called "Half-Blood prince" suggested I use the below formula to generate this sequence

```
an=A*n^3+B*n^2+C*n+D
```

I have in the past used *int*, *double* etc. then within a loop  say `int i = i*7;` but obviously in this case the mathematical forumla is alittle more complicated, so I'm here to ask how can I utilise the above whithin C#

Link to thread: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985704/what-is-the-formula-to-generate-this-number-sequence-1-7-14-30

Comment: Did the first comment on that post not answer your question? "maybe try an=1.33*n^3−7.5*n^2+19.166*n−12". Looks like he already handed you the required values for A, B, C, and D.

Comment: I don't know how to utilise this within C# hence my question here. If you do, could you please give a C# example

Comment: It's just simple arithmetic. Are you confused by the `^` operator? That's exponentiation. You can use `Math.Pow` in C# for that.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, the given formula won't produce integers (unless you round the numbers), so I don't know if it fits your needs. How many of these numbers do you need? It looks from your post that four would be enough.

Comment: Kevin, within C# if I but an "a" before another letter it expects "ai" or "an" to be a variable itself

Comment: Are you asking how to create a variable? `int an = whatever;`.

Comment: When he states "an", is he suggesting the name of a new variable. I assumed it meant an operation was to be performed on the output of the right side of the forumla

Comment: *an* is just the nth number in sequence *a*.

Comment: If your question is _"Can you translate this formula to C#?"_, then mine is: _"What have you tried?"_.

Comment: You have your answers, but are you sure you're not using a sledgehammer to crack a nut? You sure what you really want isnt just an array with your pre-canned numbes in `[1,7,14,30]`?

Comment: Also, the next numbers in this sequence (63,120,211) seem to bare no significance whatsoever. Is 63 2 months? is 120 3 months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use that equation in C# like so:

```
public static double Calculate(double n)
{
    return (1.33*(n*n*n)) - (7.5 * (n*n)) + (19.16 * n) - 12;
}
```

And call it with

```
Console.WriteLine(Calculate(1)); 
Console.WriteLine(Calculate(2)); 
Console.WriteLine(Calculate(3)); 
Console.WriteLine(Calculate(4));
```

The above writes

> 0.99
>   6.96
>   13.89
>   29.76

Which is your required sequence, if you rounded each result to an integer.

Live example: http://rextester.com/TIU97590

Comment: I think you need to cube that first `n`.

Comment: +1 for link to rextester.com, great site, didn't knew it before.

Comment: I suspect that for large indices, the produced rounded numbers will slowly move away from the right sequence. But what is the "right sequence" anyway? It cannot be deduced from four numbers only, can it; the pattern is not obvious. It seems to be something week-related.

Comment: @PatriceGahide - I agree totally. This is a blunt-force way of producing some 'odd' sequuence. I suspect what the OP really wants is an Array with the values `[1,7,14,30]` in it.

Comment: It is
1 day, 1 week, 2 weeks, 4 weeks etc.

Comment: @Jamiec That was my first thought but he didn't answer my question.

Comment: @CheckLater Define "etc." Please give three or four more numbers. This is really unclear. I don't think you need such a complex formula at all.

Comment: @CheckLater - if thats all it is store your numbers in an array - there is absolutely no need to "calculate" this sequence if you already know it!

Comment: For instance, how is 30 four weeks whereas 14 is two and 63 is 9(?)? You have to define "week".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void PrintSerial(int _elements)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= _elements; i++)
    {
        int value = (int)Math.Round(((1.33 * Math.Pow(i, 3)) -
                       (7.5 * Math.Pow(i, 2)) +
                       (19.166 * Math.Pow(i, 1)) - 12));
        Console.Write("{0} ", value);
    }
}
```

And you call it with `PrintSerial(5);` for example. It will print `1 7 14 30 63`

References:

[Math.Pow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Good answer, You do know that `Console.WriteLine` has an overload that does the same as `String.Format`? So that last line could just be `Console.WriteLine("{0} ",value)`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to round the numbers, just use correct calculation like this:

```
((4.0/3.0)*Math.Pow(i, 3)) - (7.5 * Math.Pow(i, 2)) + ((115.0/6.0) * i) - 12);
```

Check .net [fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f5ATQI).

The question is, why do you need to calculate this? Do you need only 4 values from sequence or more?